# Why is an instance of my class not being recognised in the method parameters?

Tags: python, class, parameter-passing

I am having an issue in Python with using a class instance attribute as the default value of a method parameter. Let me show you the code which is spitting out an error:

```
class Table():

    # then a bunch of other methods and an __init__

    def print_table(self,message = f'Current bet: {human.bet}'):
        
        self.human_cards(human.hold_cards)
        self.info_lines(human,cpu,message)
        self.cpu_cards(cpu.hold_cards)
        
        for item in self.hum_print:
            print(item)
        for item in self.info_print:
            print(item)
        for item in self.cpu_print:
            print(item)
```

my error is :

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-bf1a6f19a3b1> in <module>
----> 1 class Table():
      2 
      3 
      4     def __init__(self, length, height, card_width = 10, card_spacing = 5):
      5         self.length = length

<ipython-input-7-bf1a6f19a3b1> in Table()
     44         self.info_print = [line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6]
     45 
---> 46     def print_table(self,message = f'Current bet: {human.bet}'):
     47 
     48         self.human_cards(human.hold_cards)

NameError: name 'human' is not defined
```

`human` is a instance of a `Player` class and I use the attribute `human.bet` in other methods in this `Table` class perfectly fine. No instance of the `Table` class is called before `human` is defined, is there a way to use an attribute in this way?

Comment: `human` needs to be defined at the time of *class definition*. It is clearly not. Just use `= None` as a placeholder and check it in the function body. - *"No instance of the Table class is called before human is defined"* - yeah, but the class cannot even be *defined* if `human` is not defined, as you are using it as part of the definition of one of its methods.

Comment: Where is `human` defined exactly? Please provide a [mre]. I want to post an answer, but without the context, it's hard to give good advice. Marco's probably right though, you should probably use `=None` as a sentinel value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will always raise NameError until name 'human' is present in the same scope where class table is defined (before table class definition). You can add name by importing it or defining it in the same module.

```
from some_module import human

class Table():
    def print_table(self,message = f'Current bet: {human.bet}'):
```

or

```
human = Player()

class Table():
    def print_table(self,message = f'Current bet: {human.bet}'):
```

Anyways its a bad dependency.

Comment: Because it's a default parameter, `human` could also be defined at the top level of the class, so long as it's defined before `print_table`. Inside a function you can't make such unqualified references, but in the default parameters you can.

Comment: Thanks folks, this answers my question. It is my first project using classes, so I am still a bit wooly on some things.